# Ignore case when trying to match file names using find command in Linux

Tags: linux, search, case-insensitive

Right now, all I know to use is:

```
find / -name string.*
```

that is case sensitive and it won't find files named:

```
1string.x
STRing.x
string1.x
```

How can I search so that all the above would be returned in the search to a case-insensitive matching?

Comment: should be under http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Or you could use `find / | grep -i string`

Comment: `find` does this natively. Creating another process just to do that is going to make it slower.

Comment: True but it's easy to remember and consistent with the software tools pattern. Find does do shell globbing on plain old `-name`, it is true.

Answer (score 26):

Use the `-iname` option instead of `-name`.

Comment: what about the characters before and after the string? will -iname return names with extra characters?

Comment: @micah: If you tell it to. `find . -iname '*string*'`

Comment: Ok, but `-iname` is not a Posix find option. Posix does specify shell pattern matching for `-name`.

Comment: @DigitalRoss The original poster specified the 'linux' tag, so I think assuming the GNU findutils is reasonable.

Answer (score 6):

This works as well, if you want to avoid the single quotes:

```
find . -iname \*string\*
```

Comment: find . -iname \*YOUR_PATTERN\* -type f

Answer (score 2):

Use -iname in find for case insensitive file name matches.

Answer (score 1):

If the system you are in does not have the `find` command provided by the GNU utils package, you can use the `-name` tag alone with POSIX bracket expressions as

```
find . -name '*[Ss][Tt][Rr]ing*'
```